# The accordion don't stop when applying a hover mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am using the accordion to display the subcategories of each category.

My Problem is that I can't go to the subcategory of a category because it closes after the mouse out.

I want to  keep the same architecture of the html:
**Currently I have**

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('ul.r-list h1').hover(function() {
    $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideDown()
  }, function() {
    $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideUp()
  }).find($(this).next()).hide()
});
```

```css
ul.r-list li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="r-list">
  <li>
    <h1>
      <span class="collapse resp-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-lg"></i></span>
      <a class="category Parent" href="">Parent Category</a>
      <span>(8)</span>
    </h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="category sub-category children1" href="">sub Category1</a>
        <span>(5)</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="category sub-category children2" href="">sub Category2</a>
        <span>(1)</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="category sub-category children3" href="">sub Category3</a>
        <span>(2)</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Expected result:**
when I go to child category the animation stop and when I mouse out it automatically closes.

**Current result:**
when i go to child category the animation didn't stop

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to the hover event on the whole `ul.r-list li` so the `mouse out` event does not fire when you move from `h1` to `ul`. Then in the event handler functions find `ul` inside current `this` element and slide it up/down.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('ul.r-list li').hover(function () {
      $(this).find('ul').stop(true,true).slideDown()
    },function(){
      $(this).find('ul').stop(true,true).slideUp() 
    }).find($(this).next()).hide()
});
```

```css
ul.r-list li ul {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="r-list">
 <li>
  <h1>
   <span class="collapse resp-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-lg"></i></span>
   <a class="category Parent" href="">Parent Category</a>
   <span>(8)</span>
  </h1>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a class="category sub-category children1" href="">sub Category1</a>
    <span>(5)</span>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="category sub-category children2" href="">sub Category2</a>
    <span>(1)</span>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="category sub-category children3" href="">sub Category3</a>
    <span>(2)</span>
   </li>
  
   
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Add a class like `r-hasSublist` to the common LI element (that wraps H1 and the UL sublist).  Target that class to keep the hover's `mouseenter` event active.

Inside the `.hover()` method you can than use simply `$('> ul', this).stop().slideToggle();`

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $('.r-hasSublist').hover(function() {
    $('> ul', this).stop().slideToggle();
  });
  
});
```

```css
.r-hasSublist ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="r-list">
  <li class="r-hasSublist">
    <h1>
      <span class="collapse resp-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-lg"></i></span>
      <a class="category Parent" href="">Parent Category</a>
      <span>(8)</span>
    </h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="category sub-category children1" href="">sub Category1</a>
        <span>(5)</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="category sub-category children2" href="">sub Category2</a>
        <span>(1)</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="category sub-category children3" href="">sub Category3</a>
        <span>(2)</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```